# VUE: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In the **Net Ninja Vue Tutorial** `19` on YouTube, I am going through **nested components** where I wish to display a `ul` list using `v-for` and `v-bind: key`.

I keep getting the following error and it won't compile.
I am new to Vue, can Guru out there please help me out here. Currently, my `vue` version is `@vue/cli 4.4.6` and the `npm` is at `6.13.4`.

```js
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="(ninja, index) in ninjas" v-bind:key="index"></li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      ninjas: ['Ryu','Ken','Yoshi']
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**ERROR**

```bash
ERROR in ./src/Ninjas.Vue
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <template>
|     <ul>
|         <li v-for="(ninja, index) in ninjas" v-bind:key="index"></li>
 @ ./src/main.js 3:0-34
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

Comment: Do you have a closing tag `</li>` in your original code?

Comment: Initially no, but added it and still the same error message

Answer (score 15):

You need also to check if you have added the below code in your webpack.mix.js file:

```
 mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue();
```

We added  the .vue() function because now with latest update, webpack configurations are changed so we need to make changes according to it.

Hope it helps someone out

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel 8 if you want to compile Vue, before running make sure you have installed "vue-template-compiler" & "vue-loader" with npm.

If it's not installed try this:

```zsh
npm install vue-template-compiler

npm install vue-loader
```

Now you can run `npm run watch`.

Answer (score 3):

add in `.vue()` to my web pack worked for me

```
mix.js('resources/js/landing/quote.js', 'public/js/landing').vue();
```

Answer (score 1):

First there's nothing wrong with the code in `Ninjas.Vue`

the problem is in the filename `Ninjas.Vue` should be renamed to  `Ninjas.vue`

- because  component in `vue` ends with an extension `.vue` , lowercase

Answer (score 0):

just add mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue() and  run  command

npm install vue-loader@^16.2.0 --save-dev --legacy-peer-deps

then remove  this errors